# Dealing with threads

Tags: android, multithreading, ondestroy

What is the proper way to manage threads working in the background?

For example, I have Activity that creates several threads. I need to do following:
**1) Destroy all threads when Application is destroyed

2) Pause threads created within Activity if user navigate away from Activity

3) Destroy threads created within Activity if Activity is destroyed**

The only thing that come to my mind would be to have all threads variables declared as public the to be able to issue t.destroy() or something similar on these events that I listed above.
First, I am not sure if this is right way at all, and secondly, I don't like it because I will have to change code to make sure I can reference all threads I created.

For example, I have situation where my Activity instantiate new object (ex. LoadImages.class) and that objects creates several thread depending on how many images is to be loaded. The threads are not visible from the calling activity.

**So, do I have to pass threads references to calling activity, or there is some way to know who is the parent of the thread and destroy only thread with particular parent Activity?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `LoadingImages` I think there is a simple solution: have a public method on `LoadingImage` called `release` that will allow it to release its own resources.

If each of your activities is destroying its own threads, I don't see the need for your step 1.

Comment: Yes. You are right. No need for step 1. How about destroying threads? Do you keep reference to each thread that is created (in LoadingImage) so you can destroy or stop them (in release)?

Comment: Well, usually you should be using an `AsyncTask` and calling `task.cancel(false)`. `Thread` doesn't expose a good interface for stopping. See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#destroy()

Comment: Going with AsyncTask is seems the best way since it provides cancel method. I have corrected my code and added new method into Loading class and everything works nice.